# Fallout 3 Trouble on the Homefront trophy isn't unlocking

Tags: achievements, ps3, fallout-3

I finished the Trouble on the Homefront quest but the trophy hasn't unlocked. Is it a glitch? Do I have to finish the quest in a certain way to unlock the trophy? I don't have any DLCs installed.

Comment: There are some bugs listed on the wikia page: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Trouble_on_the_Homefront#Bugs. Do any of those apply to you? It's discussed a few other places as well: http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/fallout-3/trophy/4285-Trouble-on-the-Homefront.html, http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/939932-fallout-3/answers/295528-to-unlock-quottrouble-on-the-homefrontquot-i-have-done-what-is-needed-but. Please do some research. If you don't see the answer to your issue anywhere, come back and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: @DCShannon I did check those two pages before asking the question but those don't actually apply to my problem. Cause, I was able to finish the quest, I didn't have any problem with that. I even got the "Quest Completed" just the trophy didn't pop up. Although, this happen to me "Icon pc Icon xbox360 It is possible that the final objective (Leave Vault 101 forever) will stay marked as unfinished, even after you've completed the quest. [verified]"

Comment: That's critical information that needs to be in the question. That means you didn't complete the quest, and therefore didn't get the trophy. The focus should be on resolving that issue.

Comment: Can you just load a save from shortly before you "finished" the quest?

Comment: @DCShannon But, I did finished it. Cause in the menu, it's on the completed quests. And as I say the "Quest Completed" did pop up. And yes, a did a save shortly before and keeps happening the same.

Comment: Well then now I'm confused. You said the last objective was never completed, but also that the quest is in the Complete Quests section. Is it in there, but with the last objective unmarked? Does the objective still show up on the screen for you, as if you were still doing the quest? Either way, that sounds like a bug. If you followed the steps to complete the quest outlined on the wiki page, you should get the trophy.

Comment: @DCShannon Exactly, even though the Quest is in the "Quest Completed" section, the last objetive is unmarked, but, you know the "Quest completed" pop up after you finish a big quest? well, that one alredy appear, so, the game claims I finished it. I even saw some comments that, even if is unmarked it doesn't matter, the trophy should pop up. So, that's why i'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments of the post you have encountered a glitch in the game. After leaving Vault 101 the quest should progress and the task to "Leave the Vault forever" should complete. There are no other requirements to earn the achievement apart from finishing the quest.

The only solution to this would be to replay the quest again using an old save or restarting the quest using console commands (which are unavailable on the PS3 and Xbox 360 unfortunately)